# Workaround for Java Concordion substring ("contains")

Tags: java, testing, concordion

As i see, Concordion test framework makes only exact strings/numbers matching.

*Is there any workaround to test the result contains some substring?*

For instance, i test a service returns an error in format `ERROR 123`, and the test should be valid for any error number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of answers depending on the desired readability of the output and the amount of effort you want to put in.

1) Easiest is to use `assert-true` to check for the substring, eg:

```
The service [returns](- "#result=callService()") an [ERROR](- "c:assert-true=containsSubstring(#result, #TEXT)")
```

with fixture:

```
@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
public class StackOverflow {

    public String callService() {
        // call your service here
    }

    public boolean containsSubstring(String input, String check) {
        return input.contains(check);
    }
}
```

The downside of this is that, on failure, the error message will just show:

[image: message showing '== false']

2) Same fixture as 1, with `containsSubstring` throwing an exception on failure. Concordion would then show the failure as a stack trace:

```
public boolean containsSubstring(String input, String check) {
    if (!input.contains(check)) {
        throw new AssertionError("'" + input + "' does not contain '" + check + "'");
    }
    return true;
}
```

On failure this shows:

[image: stack trace showing '200 OK' does not contain 'ERROR']

3) Use `assertEquals` to check:

```
The service [returns](- "#result=callService()") an [ERROR](- "?=contains(#result, #TEXT)")
```

with fixture:

```
public String contains(String input, String check) {
    if (!input.contains(check)) {
        return input;
    }
    return check;
}
```

This shows the "best" error message:[image: message showing 'ERROR' in strikethrough, then '200 OK']

4) You could write an extension, which would save you from defining such a `contains` method in every fixture (or inheriting them all from one superclass fixture):

Spec:

```
The service [returns](- "#result=callService()") an [ERROR](- "cx:isError=#result")
```

Fixture:

```
@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
@ConcordionOptions(declareNamespaces={"cx", "urn:error-extension:2017"})
@Extensions(ErrorExtension.class)
public class StackOverflow {

    public String callService() {
        // call your service here
    }
}
```

Extension:

```
public class ErrorExtension implements ConcordionExtension {
    private List<AssertListener> listeners = new ArrayList<AssertListener>();

    public void addAssertEqualsListener(AssertListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeAssertEqualsListener(AssertListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTo(ConcordionExtender concordionExtender) {
        concordionExtender.withCommand("urn:error-extension:2017", "isError", new AbstractCommand() {
            @Override
            public void verify(CommandCall commandCall, Evaluator evaluator, ResultRecorder resultRecorder) {
                Check.isFalse(commandCall.hasChildCommands(), "Nesting commands inside an 'isError' is not supported");

                Element element = commandCall.getElement();

                String actual = (String) evaluator.evaluate(commandCall.getExpression());

                if (actual.contains("ERROR")) {
                    resultRecorder.record(Result.SUCCESS);
                    announceSuccess(element);
                } else {
                    resultRecorder.record(Result.FAILURE);
                    announceFailure(element, "String containing ERROR", actual);
                }
            }
        });
        listeners.add(new AssertResultRenderer());
    }

    private void announceSuccess(Element element) {
        for (AssertListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.successReported(new AssertSuccessEvent(element));
        }
    }

    private void announceFailure(Element element, String expected, Object actual) {
        for (AssertListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.failureReported(new AssertFailureEvent(element, expected, actual));
        }
    }
}
```

which also shows the "best" error message:[image: message showing 'ERROR' in strikethrough, then '200 OK']

Comment: the main disadvantage of all these methods: i should define such a `contains` method in every test class (or inherit all of them from one). Besides this, the third solution so far looks the best, IMHO

Comment: I've added a 4th solution, which should meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

For testing your logic you can go for 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Comment: Sorry, but question is about Concordion, not Mockito